Running Python package and unittests do not work at the same time
Error in structuring and running Python code
Directory Structure:
project
├── library
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── time_calculator.py
│   ├── distance_calculator.py
│   ├── weight_calculator.py
│   ├── calculator.py
│   │
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── unittests_calculator.py
│
├── __init__.py
└── README.txt

SCENARIO 1:
code inside the file calculator.py
from time_calculator import TimeCalculator
from distance_calculator import DistanceCalculator
from weight_calculator import weightCalculator

class Calculator:
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    calculator = Calculator()
    calculator.calculate()

code inside the file tests/unittests_calculator.py...
from library.calculator import Calculator

. . . 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Observations for Scenario 1:
In case of the above scenario,

[python calculator.py] Works!

[python -m unittest tests/unittests_calculator.py] DOES NOT WORK!
Error: No module named 'time_calculator'


SCENARIO 2:
code inside the file calculator.py (notice that I have added library. - package name, before the module name)
from library.time_calculator import TimeCalculator
from library.distance_calculator import DistanceCalculator
from library.weight_calculator import weightCalculator

class Calculator:
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    calculator = Calculator()
    calculator.calculate()

code inside the tests/unittests_calculator.py
from library.calculator import Calculator
. . . 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Observations for Scenario 2:
In case of the above scenario,

[python calculator.py] DOES NOT WORK!

[python -m unittest tests/unittests_calculator.py] Works!
Error: No module named 'library.time_calculator'; 'library ' is not a package


QUESTION
I have __init__.py, which represents library as a package. but still something is not right, Not sure where am I wrong?!
How can I resolve it to work for both; running the unittests and running the code?
NOTE: I am using python-3.9.13

Does this answer your question? Relative imports for the billionth time

tl;dr: Use relative imports and run calculator as module as well.

Is calculator.py a script, or do you expect to import it as a module as well?

@matszwecja I did use relative import like from .time_calculator import TimeCalculator but still the same errors as above. However, I dodn't understand what do you mean by running the calculator.py as module?

@chepner calculator.py is a script and has __main__

Then it's much easier to store it outside the directory library/, because it's not part of the package being defined from that directory.

Tried several scenarios, including the one you're suggesting. But none would work for both running the tests and the module. Only one would work. eventhoug there is an init.py file in the project  too

Depending on what process executes python code (unittest, module invocation by import, click app etc.) it might be assuming different "home directory".
In your case what I would do is - specify custom PYTHONPATH specifically for unit testing as in:
PYTHONPATH=project python -m unittest tests/unittests_calculator.py

Relative imports work fine, only if all calling of python code is facilitated through importing it inside module.

I tried with -m and still getting this...
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package it's one of the above is working with the changes I mentioned in the question. I tried with and without 'pdm' virtual environment, doesn't solve the issue

Try specifying PYTHONPATH though in front of python -m ... - so python will know it's a base directory (hence library will become first level)

Tried command PYTHONPATH=library python -m unittest_calculator, many different  ways... but by changing directories/names etc. but the error is consistent ModuleNotFoundError: No module names library (on the import line in the uittest )

you need to take one directory above library

tried that as well. Moved the tests directory into the project directory , parallel to the library. Still won't work! If I add library.time_calculator etc., then the tests work fine. but not the python calculator.py  (nor pyhton -m calculator) nor PYTHONPATH=library python -m calculator vice versa

Change your directory structure to:
project
├── library
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── time_calculator.py
│   ├── distance_calculator.py
│   └── weight_calculator.py
│
├── calculator.py
│   
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── unittests_calculator.py
│
└── README.txt

Neither caculator.py nor tests are part of the library package; they are a script and another package, respectively, that use the library package.
calculator.py then imports the other modules from the top-level package library:
from library.time_calculator import TimeCalculator
from library.distance_calculator import DistanceCalculator
from library.weight_calculator import weightCalculator

class Calculator:
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    calculator = Calculato()
    calculator.calculate()

When you run calculator.py, make sure that project is on your search path so that library can be found. (This will happen automatically, here, because project is the directory that contains calculator.py.
Similarly, when you run your tests, make sure that project is on the search path, both so it can see calculator.py as a module and library as a package (because I assume unittests_calculator.py will attempt to import both.)

If the other three *_calculator.py files are similarly scripts and not modules, then library probably should not exist as a package at all.

just modified the directory structure as suggested, now the relative path works in the *_calculator.py  like from .time_calculator import TimeCalculator and in the calculator.py as from library.time_calculator import TimeCalculator. and the module can be executed. But the tests are failing and the error is ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'library'

... and the error stays the same no matter I have __init__.py inside the library or not. But Calculator.py would still work!

... if I put a . infront of libaray like from .libary.time_calculator import TimeCalculator  in the calculator.py, then tests would work fine but not the calculator.py`

Don't use relative imports. calculator.py, as a script, imports library.time_calculator, with library as a top-level package, not as a module in the same package as calculator.py.

Relative imports are for importing one module from another, not for importing a module into a script.
